# Solr filter query cache and autowarming

Tags: solr

For the solr autowarming, is there any way to autowarm the filter queries which are executed before?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Create firstSearcher and newSearcher event listeners as documented here on the Solr wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#newSearcher_and_firstSearcher_Event_Listeners

It will look like this in your solrconfig.xml

```
<listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
  <arr name="queries">
    <!-- seed common sort fields -->
    <lst> <str name="q">anything</str> <str name="sort">name desc, price desc, populartiy desc</str> </lst>
    <!-- seed common facets and filter queries -->
    <lst> <str name="q">anything</str>
          <str name="facet.field">category</str>
          <str name="fq">inStock:true</str>
          <str name="fq">price:[0 TO 100]</str>
    </lst>
  </arr>
</listener>
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. Basically what I'm looking for is dynamic autowarming. In the example configuration you gave is static. I need autowarm the last real filter query received by solr server.

Comment: My understanding of autowarming is that that's exactly what autowarming does, that it migrates the query caches from the dying searcher to the new one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. So the right answer to my question is to set the autowarmCount to a non-zero value in the solrconfig.xml. Could you change your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @AndyLester: Thanks for posting but what's the way to warm up filter queries for a category field with 1000 possible values. Would I need to write 1000 lines manually in the solrconig.xml  or what is the format?

Comment: Yes, that's what you would have to do.  That said, try analyzing your users' search history (assuming you dump user queries to a log) and see if some categories get more use than others.  I wrote a program to do so at work, and found that out of the thousands of FQs that went into queries in a month of actual traffic, 14 FQs were responsible for the 99th percentile.  Those 14 FQs are what are in the warmers.